# Java performance in Air Native Extension, how do I optimize?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

I have simulatin with 30 airplanes that I want to run on an Android Phone.

I coded the whole thing in AS3 but figured there would be a boost in performance if I'd use Java in as a Native Extension.

The simlation is a library of 30 units. The simulation calculates distance and rotation between all the units. That is about 870 iteration with many distance and rotation calculations.

**My ANE on Java runs about 50x slower than my AS3 version.**

The problem seems to be calling setObjectAt() on an FREArray multiple times. I guess this conversion of Java to AS3 is slow. Is there a way to optimize getting the variables back from Java to AS3?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that AS3 performance is not that different from standard Java performance, when used as a Native Extension.

However, thanks to the Android NDK, which allowed me to rebuild the library in C++, I am not at an performance increase of about 20x.

So if you are looking for that performance edge on Android from AS3: Use the NDK.